# TypeScript inclusion flow

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, systemjs, amcharts

I am trying to properly include a third party module in TypeScript and Angular 2 using SystemJS. In this case, the third party library happens to be amCharts, but presumably this could be any library.

Here's what I'm currently doing (and it works):

- Install the library with npm
- Load it in my `index.html` layout:

index.html:

```
<script src="node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/amcharts.js"></script>
<script src="node_modules/amcharts3/amcharts/serial.js"></script>
```

- Then I simply use it in my component:

Component:

```
export class GraphComponent {
  ngOnInit() {
    AmCharts.makeChart(...); // draw chart
  }
}
```

This works and my graph renders fine, but my TypeScript compiler (in Atom) complains that it "[c]annot find name 'AmCharts'" in my component file. This makes sense, since I never declared it in that file. Including the two scripts just kind of makes the name globally available.

Something makes me think that what I really should be doing is

1. Somehow leverage SystemJS so as to not manually include the scripts in my `index.html`
2. Use TypeScripts `import` statement to load the library instead of depending on a global variable

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the question? You already know what you need to do, just do it.

Comment: @BryanChen Like I said, it works, but I don't think it's the best way. I list two points that I don't know how to implement that I think would make this better.

Answer (score 0):

Declaration files (*.d.ts) provide TypeScript declarations for structures in JavaScript code. The best place to look is [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped), and you can find the declaration file for AmCharts [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/amcharts).

You can tell the transpiler about the declaration file by adding a line that references it:

```
/// <reference path="AmCharts.d.ts" />
```

Comment: Yup. This will solve your problem. Put that line where you need amcharts

Comment: Note that instead of using a script, you probably want to create a global shim for am charts. And yes, "import AmCharts from 'amcharts" is way better practice than assuming a global variable. (You will still need the reference path to make ts work)

Comment: @MattScarpino I put this at the top of my component file `/// <reference path="../../../typings/main/definitions/AmCharts/AmCharts.d.ts"/>` (taken from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/master/amcharts/AmCharts.d.ts)), but it still can't find the name 'AmCharts'.

Also, @UAvalos, how do I go about creating a shim and/or using import instead of using the global variable?

Comment: @dchacke AmCharts.d.ts declares `AmCharts` as a module, so in addition to the reference path line, you'll need to import features from the module. I'd try something like `import * as Amcharts from "Amcharts"`.

Comment: @MattScarpino Progress! It now knows the name 'AmCharts'. However, once I use it, I get the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
 Evaluating http://localhost:3000/AmCharts
 Error loading http://localhost:3000/app/boot.js` in my browser console. I've seen this before, I think it's a SystemJS error.

A second issue is that the typings don't seem to include a `makeChart` method :(